# wait for the emitter listeners to be set before fulfilling the promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, eventemitter

I'm working with some external lib that provide some function that returns instance of the EventEmitter object. Those functions needs to be invoked in a certain order and are implemented using nested callbacks in the library example.

I would like to be able to make use of Promises to clean up my code a little and I tried something like that:

```
const messageEmitters = await getMessages(FetchMessageEmitter)
const messagesBody = await getMessageBody(messagesEmitters[0])
```

my problem here is when the node interpreter arrives at the messagesBody the eventEmitters passed has an argument does not have listeners yet, they are defined, but the amount on active listeners (emitter._eventCount) is set to zero during the primary phase of the event loop.

But in the next phase the listeners are active. I think this might come from of my using of Promises. I was thinking about some kind of solution to listen for all the listeners defined before fulfilling the promise but I don't know how to do that.

```
/*
* This should resolve an array of EventEmitters (one per messages)
*/
const getMessages = async (emitter) => {
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
    let _messages = []
    
    emitter.on('message', m => _messages.push(m))

    emitter.once('end', () => fulfill(_messages))

    emitter.once('error', error => reject(error))
  })
}

/*
* This one should resolve some data after getting the body of the message
*/
const getMessageBody = async (emitter) => {
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
    let _body = null
    
    emitter.on('body' => (stream) {
      // do something with the stream
    })
   
    emitter.once('end', () => { /* fulfill the promise */ })

    emitter.once('error', error => reject(error))
  })
}
```

Comment: The `body` event on the message is likely to be emitted _before_ you register a handler for it in your `getMessageBody` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to set up the individual body listeners before fulfilling the promise that receives the emitters:

```
// very much like getMessages(), except this resolves to an array of
// promises that themselves resolve to an array of message bodies
const getBodyPromises = async (emitter) => {
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
    let _bodyPromises = []
    
    // call the OP's get message here, so the body promise is set up
    // before control returns to the emitter-creating code
    emitter.on('message', m => {
      let bodyPromise = getMessageBody(m)
      _bodyPromises.push(bodyPromise)
    });

    emitter.once('end', () => fulfill(_bodyPromises))

    emitter.once('error', error => reject(error))
  })
}

// use the OP's getMessageBody as-is
const getMessageBody = async (emitter) => { ... }
```

Now the caller expects `getBodyPromises()` to return a promise that resolves to an array of promises.

```
const bodyPromises = await getBodyPromises(FetchMessageEmitter)
const messagesBodies = await Promise.all(bodyPromises);
```

You can still handle the body promises individually if you need to. Just loop them attaching a `.then()` to each.